# Cocoa OpenGL always white

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

Everytime I run my Cocoa App with an OpenGL view I get a white window.  What I expect to happen is a black window will show up.

I've verified with a breakpoint that my drawRect method gets called.

Code below.

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <GLUT/GLUT.h>

@interface OpenlGLTest : NSOpenGLView

- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;
@end
```

.m

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import "OpenlGLTest.h"

@implementation OpenlGLTest

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)bounds
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
@end
```

My project builds without warnings and errors.  I'm at a loss as to why my screen is white and not black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`. That last `0` in your code is the alpha coefficient, so it's just showing whatever is behind the `GLView`.